# Javascript Detect Screen Resolution, change css, crop images accordingly

Tags: javascript, image, resolution, detect, crop

So I know how to change the css depending on the resolution via javascript.

How would one go about 'cropping' an image depending on the screen resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can get the screen details from [window.screen](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml) - though personally I would recommend just finding out how big the current window is, the only reason not to is if you are going to resize the window and that is very frowned upon.

Once you know the sizes and how big you need to make your images, I find that images are cropped easiest by placing them inside a containing DIV with `overflow: hidden;` set.  You can then size the containing DIV to the size required and set the `top` and `left` CSS attributes od the image to the negative values of the coordinate you want for the top-left visible corner.

```
<div class="crop-container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="something-400x400.jpg" style="top: -100px; left: -100px;" width="400" height="400" alt="Something" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yea I already thought of that method, was curious to know if there was a javascript solution, thanks for your contribution though. By the way wouldn't you have the div set to overflow:hidden and you would change the size of that div upon screen resolution then position the image inside accordingly, not the other way round?

Comment: @Daryl Yes, sorry was rushing as its very late and put the top/left on the wrong bit, fixed now.  I assumed you were going to do that via JavaScript, I was just showing the HTML constructs that you would need to manipulate.

Comment: Ahh no problem. It's probably the method I'm going to stick with anyway. Else I'll just cause myself unnecessary hassle haha. Get some sleep.