# crop image if screen resolution less then 1280

Tags: html, css, image

So the last question I've found is similar, here from [2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272786/javascript-detect-screen-resolution-change-css-crop-images-accordingly)

I have a picture 1920 px wide.
I made it resize proportionally from left and right.
But I need it stop resizing if resolution goes less then 1280 and just to cut it both (left/right) sides and stay centered if res >1280.

```
.mainImg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 558px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I guess for that I need a wrapper with overflow hidden, I tried a bunch of options but none of them worked.

May be anyone already knows the solution? I would be very grateful!

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Main part of the webpage -->
        <img src="img/main_01.jpg" class="mainImg shadow" alt="seo matters" />
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
```

Comment: can you post your html

Comment: it's a simple template of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me a little while back, http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Maybe you could change it to meet your needs.

Comment: Looks like what I want, let me try this.

Comment: This is a one sweet link )) Thanks, still have to work on it, but it's already centering what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Set `min-width: 1280px;` then it should stop resizing at 1280px.

Comment: Yes, but it still shows an left part of image, but not the central and thats what is a main idea.

Comment: Okay, so you want the picture to become smaller until its 1280px in width and any further resizing of the window should move it to the left!?

Comment: if screen resolution is smaller then 1280px, I want it to stop resizing (that is done), and don't show a left part of picture but a central.

Comment: Try it with the event that triggers on window resize and set the left position of the picture to - the half of the window with, somehow like this: `$( window ).resize(function() {
  if($(window).innerWidth <= 1280){
 var imageElementStyle = document.getElementById('your images id').style;
 imageElementStyle.left = -($(window).innerWidth / 2;)}
});`

Comment: Thanks, I can't use jQuery this way, client wants a graceful degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tom Chew-head Millard for the link.
This (edited) code works how I wanted.

```
 img.mainPic {
  /* Set rules to dimensions */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1280px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.mainPic {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -640px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```